# Disable rendering some md and html files in Pelican

Tags: python, pelican

#### 1. Briefly

I don't find, how I can to disable rendering some files with `md` and `html` extensions.

#### 2. Detail

I use Pelican and write my articles use Markdown markup. For example, [**I want to create custom 404 page in GitHub Pages**](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site/). I need to have 2 files in root directory of my site: `404.md` and `404.html`. I create these files in my `content` folder → I run `pelican content` command → I get output.

```c++
D:\Kristinita>pelican content
WARNING: Meta tag in file D:\Kristinita\content\404.html does not have a 'name' attribute, skipping. Attributes: http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge"
ERROR: Skipping .\404.md: could not find information about 'title'
```

#### 3. Example of expected behavior

I set in `pelicanconf.py`:

```python
NOT_RENDERING = ['404.md', '404.html']
```

I run `pelican content` → `404.md` and `404.html` files don't have modifications in output.

#### 4. Did not help

1. I set in `pelicanconf.py` file:

   ```python
   STATIC_PATHS = ['']
   ```

   Files with other extension, exclude `md` and `html`, copy to the output directory without modification, warnings and errors, but it no work for `md` and `html` files.
2. I use “hack” — I write extensions in UPPERCASE. For example, I create files `404.MD` and `404.HTML` files instead of `404.md` and `404.html`. But I don't get custom 404 page in GitHub Pages with UPPERCASE extensions.
3. I find `OUTPUT_SOURCE` setting [**in documentation**](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/settings.html?highlight=OUTPUT_SOURCES#basic-settings) → I set in `pelicanconf.py`:

   ```python
   OUTPUT_SOURCES = True
   OUTPUT_SOURCES_EXTENSION = '.md'
   ```

   I run `pelican content` command → I get error and warning in output, I don't get original `404.md` in output. It don't solve my problem.

Comment: Well what *is* in `404.md`? Have you tried any of the various ignore/exclude options in [the documentation](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/settings.html)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: `permalink: /404.html` — content of my `404.md` file, see [**Creating a custom 404 page for your GitHub Pages site**](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site/). Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried any of the various ignore/exclude options in [the documentation](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/settings.html)? Why guess `NOT_RENDERING` rather than look the options up?

Comment: Also note that the docs say *"Create a HTML file named `404.html` **or** create a new Markdown file named `404.md`"*, so I'm not sure you actually need both.

Comment: The [tips](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.7.1/tips.html) suggest you generate `404.html` *from* `404.md`, again suggesting that GHP needs one or the other, not both.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: `The tips suggest you generate 404.html from 404.md, again suggesting that GHP needs one or the other, not both` — 1) Yes, I know, that I need only `404.html` or `404.md`, not both. In a question I have written both for example. Sorry, I have given an bad example. `Have you tried any of the various ignore/exclude options in the documentation?` — 2) Yes, see `Did not help` section. If I have passed something, please, tell me about it. Thanks.

Comment: My point is if you use a 404.md as shown in the tips you don't need to ignore it; Pelican will generate 404.html from it and GHP can just use that. But in the settings one obvious option seems to be *"`IGNORE_FILES = ['.#*']` A list of glob patterns. Files and directories matching any of these patterns will be ignored by the processor."*

Comment: @jonrsharpe: `IGNORE_FILES` will ignore `404.md`, i.e if I run `pelican content` command, I don't get `404.md` or any `404.md` modifications in output directory. But expected behavior — don't modify `404.md`, but output it, if I run `pelican content` command. Thanks.

Comment: Ok I think I cracked it, via an old GH issue; I don't have access to a computer here, but give my answer a go and let me know if it works out.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest moving those files into a separate directory within the content directory, e.g.:

```
content/
    static/
        404.html
        404.md
```

Then you can configure Pelican to treat that directory as a static source:

```
STATIC_PATHS = [
    'static',
]
```

and move the two files to the root of the output directory on processing:

```
EXTRA_PATH_METADATA = {
    'static/404.html': {'path': '404.html'},
    'static/404.md': {'path': '404.md'},
}
```

To make the processor ignore those files, per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/issues/1845), you will also need to set:

```
ARTICLE_EXCLUDES = [
    'static'
]
```

Comment: It don't solved my problem, I get same behavior( . In my project [**all folders is static**](https://github.com/Kristinita/KristinitaPelican/blob/master/pelicanconf.py#L86), I use [**only pages**](https://github.com/Kristinita/KristinitaPelican/blob/master/pelicanconf.py#L78), [**not articles**](https://github.com/Kristinita/KristinitaPelican/blob/master/pelicanconf.py#L82). In what environment you test your solution? Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных as far as I can tell from the current state of your repo, you *haven't* implemented this. The 404 files aren't in extra/. Also you almost certainly *don't* want everything to be counted as static; in that case, why even use Pelican? As I mentioned above, I cannot currently test this. You should try making a [mcve] rather than adding state on top of what you already have.

Comment: `Also you almost certainly don't want everything to be counted as static; in that case, why even use Pelican?` — I want, that my Markdown pages compile to HTML. If I use `STATIC_PATHS = ['']`, my Markdown files successful render to HTML, for example, [**Markdown page in content**](https://github.com/Kristinita/KristinitaPelican/blob/master/content/Sublime%20Text/SashaSublime.md) — [**HTML page in output**](https://github.com/Kristinita/Kristinita.github.io/blob/master/Sublime%20Text/SashaSublime.html). Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных static is for files you *don't* want processed, as opposed to articles and pages.

Comment: yes, I think, that it expected behavior. But actual behavior — pages processed for me, if I add folders with my pages to `STATIC_PATHS`. My question about it. Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных they *will* get processed there, unless you add them to the articles/pages exclusion lists as I show above (this is covered in the docs), but they don't *need* to be there. And if they are in a "static" directory that still doesn't mean you need to make the whole of content "static". I'd suggest you start from the basics; again, make a [mcve] to test the functionality you actually need without all of the complexity your current repo has.

Comment: I'm sorry, I get this problem, because I set `PAGE_PATHS = ['']` in my `pelicanconf.py` file. [**I add folders as values of this setting**](https://github.com/Kristinita/KristinitaPelican/blob/master/pelicanconf.py#L96) and I solve the problem. I delete soon this question; sorry, that I spend your time. Thanks.